# Load-balancing EJB calls from an EJB client

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, glassfish, ejb, cluster-computing

I'm using a JBoss cluster with a number of EJB components deployed on it. I've noticed the following:

- If I perform a JNDI lookup from an external client, the load-balancing process works as expected (i.e. a random cluster node is selected and the EJB is executed there)

  If the client is one of the EJBs (i.e. one EJB invokes another), the target EJB is always executed on the same machine as the caller

Is it possible to have the load-balancing feature in the second scenario as well? Does anybody have some experience with GlassFish?

I'm using asynchronous EJB invocation. If I employ JMS instead and call the target from a message-driven bean, I get the desired behavior, but the performance deteriorates.

Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Comment: In case 2, do you use the local or remote interface?

Comment: I use remote interfaces only. None of the EJBs is marked with @LocalBean.

Comment: When EJB is invoking a method on another EJB, are you injecting the 2nd EJB?  Is it a @Stateless bean?